# Параметры в ссылке при  создании задачи CRON

Tags: cron, cookie

```
/usr/bin/php /home/user1734/public_html/test.php?query=1
```

Таким образом задача вообще не выполняется, будто её и нет. И ещё CRON не умеет работать с cookie. Как быть?

Comment: CRON и не должен уметь работать с cookies. Не его это дело. Его дело -- задачи запускать, когда предписано.

Comment: @alexlz, а как быть? Вот я пишу авторизацию на сайте с помощью curl() и в файлик cookies.txt должны записываться cookie curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt'); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');. Но они не записываются. И что на счет параметров в ссылке?

Comment: php говорит:

    alex@ubuntu:~/ttd$ php --help
    Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]

Так что возможно так: 

    /usr/bin/php /home/user1734/public_html/test.php ?query=1

`--`  -- это если есть параметр, начинающийся с `-`

Comment: @alexlz, прописал задачу /usr/bin/php /home/user1781/public_html/monster/test.php ?query=1. В файле test.php прописал: file_put_contents('123.txt', $_GET['query']); и записывается пустая строка.

Comment: Дык нету у Вас $_GET'ов-то. Да и http-сервера-то нет. Пошукайте $argv, точнее $argv[1]. Ну а дальше -- не ко мне. По php тут должно быть немало спецов.

Comment: @alexz, хотябы объясните, что это такое: Пошукайте $argv, точнее $argv[1]

Comment: Массив такой. Параметры из командной строки (у меня)

    php a.php ?query=1

`argv[1] => "a.php"`, `argv[2] => "?query=1". Больше не знаю -- надо спецов пытать. Можно даже паяльником -- пусть сознаются.

argv -- пришло ещё из C (прародителя этих Си-подобных языков)

Да, кстати.

    php a.php ?a


дало argv [0] => "a.php" [1] => "@a" [2] => "aa". Как это расшифровывать -- понятия не имею.

Comment: @alexz, сделал! $_SERVER['argv'], а там ненужное вырезал и всё получилось. А теперь насчет того, что куки в curl'e не записываются curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt'); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');. С этим как можно решить проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызывать по крону (по расписанию) php скрипт можно двумя способами:

1. через веб сервер: обратиться к нужной ссылке через curl юникса, например

   `curl --silent http://site.ru/script.php?param1=1&param2=2`

   Тут куки поддерживаются. Читайте [документацию по curl](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_curl.htm) в linux, параметр "`-b`".
2. в командной строке, напр.

   `/usr/bin/php /home/modal/www/htdocs/script.php`

   В этом варианте куки «не поддерживаются». Но зато внутри самого скрипта вы можете использовать [php'шный cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), чтобы, в свою очередь, обратиться к какому-то веб-ресурсу, и уже в этой сессии обрабатывать куки средствами php и cURL.

Comment: @sergiks, >> обрабатывать куки средствами php и cURL

вот это как? :D

Comment: @Modal,если если не ошибаюсь,как в раз и curl_opt параметрах указываете где хранить куки.

Comment: Курить [доки по cURL](http://th.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php). Есть параметры, отвечающие за приём и сохранение кук: `CURLOPT_COOKIE, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION`.